# Still able to edit posts with pending edits

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, stack-exchange

I've noticed a inconsistency in my ability to edit posts that have a edit pending:

The normal <kbd>edit</kbd> button is disabled as it should be.
However, if the post has an edit history, I can open it, then select <kbd>edit</kbd> on one of the revisions (and edit -> save), circumventing the edit lock.

Is this functionality intentional?

Comment: If you start editing before the suggested edit is submitted then submit your edit after there is already a suggested edit, your edit kicks the suggested edit out causing insta-rejection. This is probably the same thing, from a different angle so don't think it is a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The problem is that this way, you can start editing after an edit was suggested, kicking the suggestion out, when you save it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: This isn't necessarily a rollback-related issue. The problem is that the edit option is available in the question's history.

Comment: Editing to previous revision is called rollback.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: And editing the last (aka current) version in the history? That's an edit of the current post. What I'm saying is that you can still edit the current post, even though the edit button on the question is disabled, by accessing the question's history.